# Linux find and replace (conditional)

Tags: linux, awk

I have a very specific requirement which I'm finding hard to do, I need to find and replace certain lines in a file but the problem is the text is different, the only upside is they all have a .[extension]

For example:

```
30/07/2012  14:46            17,232 training program.DOCX.ddkhqvh
08/03/2011  20:57            31,664 nutritional program.XLS.ddkhqvh
```

Needs to be:

```
F:/home/training program.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/nutritional program.XLS.ddkhqvh
```

I tried to use awk but I'm pulling my hair out.

Comment: What have you tried?  Also, all the file names have spaces?  Just some of them?

Comment: you want to replace the filename part with the fully qualified path?

Comment: Sorry some lines have more than one space in them

Comment: here is a example of the actual file http://pastebin.com/tuKwvHVM

Comment: Try my post and see if that is what you need.  I can also remove the lines not changed if you like.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$ awk '/^[0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/ { sub(/^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +/,"F:/home/"); print; }' <file.txt
F:/home/ALLERGAN Recruitment tracking sheet Template.XLS.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Holding Letter 15May12.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Amgen DBMS 2nd Mailing part 1 - Griifin Request Form.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Amgen DBMS 2nd Mailing part 2 - Griifin Request Form.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Database Letter, Reply Slip, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337,draft version 1, 19.03.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Previous DXA ladies 25.05.12.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter, 20070337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/End of Study Thank You Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Interim Thank you letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Welcome Letter,  20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/End of Study Thank You Letter,20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter,20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Interim Thank you letter,20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Welcome Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/End of Study Thank You Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/example GPMS.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Interim Thank you letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Welcome Letter,  20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/A5 EDUCATION LUNCH POSTERS - CAMPAIGN CODES.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Multiple choice Questionaire - Merseyside  26th Jan 2011.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Multiple choice Questionaire - Scotland 26th Jan 2011.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Multiple choice Questionaire - Wales  26th Jan 2011.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Multiple choice Questionaire Template  26th Jan 2011.DOC.ddkhqvh
```

This picks up only the lines in the file with initial dates and thus only modifies the file names listed in the file.

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk '/\.[[:alpha:]]+$/ {$1=$2=$3="";sub(/^ */,"F:/home/");print}' file
F:/home/ALLERGAN Recruitment tracking sheet Template.XLS.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Holding Letter 15May12.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Amgen DBMS 2nd Mailing part 1 - Griifin Request Form.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Amgen DBMS 2nd Mailing part 2 - Griifin Request Form.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Database Letter, Reply Slip, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337,draft version 1, 19.03.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Previous DXA ladies 25.05.12.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter, 20070337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/End of Study Thank You Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Interim Thank you letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Welcome Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/End of Study Thank You Letter,20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/GP Letter,20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Interim Thank you letter,20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/Welcome Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1 Draft, 9th Feb 2012.DOC.ddkhqvh
F:/home/End of Study Thank You Letter, 20070337, AMGXXXOST337, Version 1, 16.02.12.DOC.ddkhqvh
```

This change the path if line ends with `.text`.  It removes the three first field and add path.

Comment: This works only if the filename has one space in it. If it has more than one, the script will generate incorrect output.

Comment: correct it didn't work for some of them and also the rest of the line was also deleted

Comment: @ZakLewis What is the trigger to make the replace, and do you like to keep the other lines?  Also some other variation lines in your example would be nice.

Comment: other lines are not important they can go, also your script didn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print "f:/home/"$(NF-1), $(NF)}' filename.txt
```

You can try this one.
It append last two field (separated from a space) to a predefined string.

Comment: This will change all the lines `replace certain lines`

Comment: Your script nearly did it, certain lines didn't get replaced, i think it's because they have two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `cut` and `sed`?

```
$ cat spam
30/07/2012  14:46            17,232 training program.DOCX.ddkhqvh
08/03/2011  20:57            31,664 nutritional program.XLS.ddkhqvh

$ cut -c 37- spam | sed 's/^/F:\/home\//'
F:/home/training program.DOCX.ddkhqvh
F:/home/nutritional program.XLS.ddkhqvh
```

**It will work as long as the original file have the filenames starting at the 37th character.**

If you want the results in a different file, just redirect the output using `>`

```
$ cut -c 37- spam | sed 's/^/F:\/home\//' > output
```

### Edit

If your initial list of files comes from issuing a `dir >your_file` command in MS Windows, just use `dir /B >your_file` instead of `dir` to take the list of files **without** any other column, like size, date, owner, etc...  Then simply issue the following command in the Linux shell to add the folder to the beginning of each line: `sed 's/^/F:\/home\//' your_file`.

Comment: Where did you get the original output from?  It's an `ls -l` output or something like that?

Comment: Seems to be a MS Windows' `dir` output, is that correct?  If that's the case, just use `dir /B` instead of `dir`, so you can get just the filenames (without the other columns like size, date, etc...)